# I'm getting error 'ko:Invalid cache partition image type: yaffs2 (expected ext4)' when tried to launch android on emulator for device mako?

Tags: android, android-source

I followed all the steps given here: 
[Building and Running](https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html)
and target configuration was 'aosp_mako-userdebug'

Comment: Hey... any solution is there? today i also facing same pro.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I simply updated my android studio that worked for me.

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding which version you had when you faced this problem, and which version fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem by using linux tools to create an image.

1. Create a *system_new.img* file:
   `dd if=/dev/zero of=system_new.img bs=4k count=1800000`
2. Create *ext4* file system:
   `mkfs.ext4 system_new.img`
3. Override file system check (otherwise the image will not work):
   `tune2fs -c0 -i0 system_new.img`
4. Mount the image:
   `sudo mount -o loop system_new.img mount_point`
5. Copy whatever files you want.
6. Umnount the image:
   `sudo umount mount_pont`

Your image is ready!

You can check it with an *android emulator* executing:
`emulator -avd YOUR_VIRTUAL_DEVICE -system system_new.img`